# Plural form of Interrogative words

Tags: questions

I am seeking to use 's' with wh-words, such as who and what.

The phrase in context goes as such- "Empathy Map - Answering your whos and whats"

The dilemma is whether the language allows us to use it this way. Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's an idiomatic way of talking about answering your questions about who and what. I don't think it needs scare quotes, as it is a common-enough expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps in informal communication it would work, but I wouldn't consider it grammatical in formal writing—with a stylistic exception that I will discuss later.

To start, consider the case of how to use the *singular* words:

> ✘ Answering your who and what.

To make that sentence grammatical, and assuming it's in reference to a *single* question, we'd need to use something like the following:

> ✔ Answering your who and what question.

By extension, if we're talking about *multiple* questions, your original sentence (if you want something formally correct) should be rephrased as follows:

> Empathy Map - Answering your who and what questions.

This dispenses with the issue of using the plural form of the words because the subject of the sentence becomes *questions*.

---

However, you can also refer to the words *as words*. When you do this, they are no longer part of the functional sentence, and you almost always have to set them apart from the other words in some stylistic fashion. The most common method of doing this is to italicize them:

> Empathy Map - Answering your *whos* and *whats*.

Whether or not you italicize the *and* is up to how you interpret the phrase—are you counting the words as separate or are considering the entire expression as a combined thing?

This now takes the same form as:

> Be sure to follow the *dos and don'ts* of the job.
>   People often confuse the words *there*, *their*, and *they're*.

---

Or you could use quotation marks instead—either double or single. (Even in US English, single quotation marks can be used for the specific purpose of designating words as words—although UK punctuation is used.)

> Empathy Map - Answering your "whos" and "whats."
>   Empathy Map - Answering your 'whos' and 'whats'.

Again, you could put the quotation marks around all three words, if you interpreted it that way.

---

Which of the various forms you choose to use is up to you.